# Can you copy linker/additional dependancies etc to other projects

Tags: c++, linker, dependencies, visual-studio-2013

I consistently have to add directx lib files etc to all of my projects, dependencies, linker stuff etc...

Is there a file I can copy across that has all that stuff.. and I just copy it to every project that needs it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have the option of creating a [property sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that can be added to new or existing projects. Here are the basic steps.

1. Open the Property Manager (View menu).
2. Right click on a project and select "Add New Property Sheet"
3. Once the property sheet has been created/added right click on it and add your common configuration settings (the same way you do in a project's properties).

Once you've created the property sheet you can add it to new or existing projects in much the same way.

1. Open the Property Manager.
2. right click on the project you want to add the property sheet to and click "Add Existing Property Sheet".

I don't recommend copying into each project or solution directory but rather keep in in a central place much like you would a third party library (i.e. Boost).

Comment: view/Other windows/Property Manager for express... thanks a bunch man!