# Setup sdl2 for all projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

How to add libraries permanently because it always reset for all new projects. I also tried it by putting it in the same project folder.(for visualstudio)

Comment: Make a property sheet with all of the sdl information in it. Include that property sheet in new projects.

Comment: By property sheet do you mean a folder? If do so i included it but it only works for current project and for other projects all the file i had included or linked are reset to default

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792155/can-you-copy-linker-additional-dependancies-etc-to-other-projects